# How to generate uuid with PostgreSQL 8.4.4 on Ubuntu 10.04?

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, uuid, ubuntu-10.04

I am running PostgreSQL 8.4.4 with Ubuntu 10.04.

I am trying to generate uuid but can't find a way to do it.

I do have the uuid-ossp.sql in `/usr/share/postgresql/8.4/contrib/uuid-ossp.sql`

When I try this is what I get :

```
postgres=# SELECT uuid_generate_v1();
ERROR:  function uuid_generate_v1() does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT uuid_generate_v1();
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The stuff in `contrib` aren't run automatically.  You have to run it yourself to install the functions.  I don't know about the 8.4 version, but in the 8.3 version it appears to only install it per-database, so open up the database you're using in psql and issue the command `\i /usr/share/postgresql/8.4/contrib/uuid-ossp.sql`

Comment: Yes, it's per database. You could install everything in the template1 database to be sure every new database that uses this database as its template (this is the default), is created including all contrib modules.

Comment: For current versions of Postgresql (9.0+, I think), the contrib modules are packaged as extensions. Extensions are neat because they can be versioned, namespaced, and uninstalled. For example, you can install the uuid functions in the "uuid" schema by using the following command: "create extension uuid-ossp schema uuid". Then you'd access the functions like "uuid.uuid_generate_v4()".

Comment: Do `apt-get install postgresql-contrib` and then `psql -f /usr/share/postgresql/8.4/contrib/uuid-ossp.sql nameofdatabase` - just for the lazy ;)

Answer (score 1):

I saw this in my PostgreSQL travels.  It requires the pgcrypto contrib module.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION generate_uuid() RETURNS UUID AS
$$
SELECT ENCODE(GEN_RANDOM_BYTES(16), 'hex')::UUID
$$ LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE;
```

Comment: for those of us at the back of the class, to actually get stuff installed into /contrib do a sudo apt-get install postgresql-contrib. @paul thanks.

Comment: You should not declare the function as `IMMUTABLE` because you don't want to have cached reads instead of function evaluations. Declare your function as `VOLATILE` to ensure the function is executed every time it is called. See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/interactive/xfunc-volatility.html for further explanations.

Comment: I get this when I execute this function:
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "relation_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(5a0cd072-6463-2cb0-9de9-42aabb85f270) already exists.
Chaning to VOLATILE as mentioned above solves the problem though.

Comment: This doesn't generate a valid UUID, see RFC 4122. Certain bits mark the UUID version, those will be random and likely invalid most of the time.